# How to implement a synthetic benchmark?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, assembly

I'm doing my first programs in C++ and assembly code. I already know how to program in C++, but I have a lot of problems when I try to program in assembly code.
I want to do a *synthetic benchmark*, which

> *"is designed to mimic a particular type of workload on a component or system. Synthetic benchmarks do this by specially created programs that impose the workload on the component."* ***(Wikipedia)***

For example, if I want to calculate the factorial of `long fact = pow(3.0, 2000)`, how can I measure the performance of a component in C++? (And not the performance of the whole system).

The rest of the code (the calculation of fact) is done in assembly code.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you'd simply make repeated calls to `pow` from within a loop, dividing the loop-time by the number of iterations. Unless you're using a non-multitasking OS, in which case it should take the same time every time it was run, rendering the averaging loop redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Following is part of one of my benchmarks (for Linux) that uses assembly code, where repetitive calculations can be carried out without fear of over optimisation. You need to use a high resolution timer with an assembly based loop long enough for reasonable execution time. You might want to repeat calculations in the loop to fill up pipelines.

This one repeats 20M adds 10 times to find maximum speed. IntCount1 value is checked at the end as a simple integrity check

```
  C Code

   intCount1 = 0;
   max = 0;
   for (i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
       count = intCount1;
       start_time();
       _mips1Reg();
       end_time();
       count = intCount1 - count;       
       mips = (int)((double)count / 1000000.0 / secs + 0.5);
       if(mips > max) max = mips;
   }       
   mipsReg[0] = max;
   printf(" 1 Register  %7d 32 Bit Integer MIPS\n", mipsReg[0]);

 ########################################################

 Hi-Res Timer Used 

 clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp1);
 theseSecs =  tp1.tv_sec + tp1.tv_nsec / 1e9;           

 ########################################################

  Assembly Code

    global _mips1Reg       
  _mips1Reg:
      push eax
      push ebx
      push ecx
      push edx
      push edi
      mov edi, 1000000
      mov eax, [intCount1]
      align 8
  dlp:add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 1
      add eax, 3
      dec edi
      jnz dlp
      mov [intCount1], eax
      pop edi
      pop edx
      pop ecx
      pop ebx
      pop eax
      ret
```